# I am having trouble getting this adventure story done because of this error

Tags: java

I am a very early beginner and I have a project due soon to create a choose your own adventure story. I am not done yet but I am getting the error "Main.java not found" Any help? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class ChoicesStory {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChoicesStory();
  }
  
  Scanner stringReader = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner numberReader = new Scanner(System.in);

  public ChoicesStory() {
    System.out.println("You're lost in a dark forest.");
    System.out.println("You see a faint light in the distance resembling a fire.");
    System.out.println("Do you want to go towards the light or keep walking?");
    System.out.print("Enter 'light' or 'walk' ");
    String choice = stringReader.nextLine();

    if (choice.equals("light")) {
      lightStory();
    }

    if (choice.equals("walk")) {
      walkStory();

    }

  }

  public void lightStory() {
    System.out.println("You walk towards the fire and see an old man sitting on a log.");
    System.out.println("You ask him if he knows how to get back to your town.");
    System.out.println("You see the man pull out a knife and look at you menacingly.");

  }

  public void walkStory() {

  }

}
```

Comment: what is the name of your file? and how are you trying to run the program? (via an IDE or from command line?)

Comment: It looks like you are doing this: `javac Main.java`.  You should be doing this:  `javac ChoicesStory.java` followed by `java ChoicesStory`.

Comment: And probably you should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html ... which steps you through the things you need to do to compile and run a simple Java program.

Comment: And you should probably declare the class as `public`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have possible named you file as `Main.java` but inside the file the class name is `ChoicesStory`. Both these should be the same. If you were using an IDE (ex : eclipse), then it would have already shown an error. Looks like you have run the program in command line using `java Main`